# Why do we use valves with drums

Tags: instruments, drums, beginner

I have stepped by a [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/-NqaupGcCpw) showing Vienna Philharmonic, under John Williams,  playing theme from “Jurassic Park”.

In [1:44 minute](https://youtu.be/-NqaupGcCpw?t=104) of this video the drummer is doing *something* with a valve placed next to drums:

[image]

Can you explain this? What kind of drum is this? And why he is using a valve at all / like that?

Comment: Please add a description of the video content so that your question remains useful even if the link dies.

Comment: @Aaron Done! :>

Comment: Not quite what I meant. Should the link go dead, we'll need a description of what you're asking about -- that is, the drum and how it's being used. Perhaps you could take a screenshot from the video and embed the photo. The image will be preserved by SE, so won't go dead.

Comment: @Aaron Hope that now this looks better.

Comment: Yes, that's perfect. Now your question will be perfectly clear even if the video eventually becomes unavailable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a kettledrum, aka timpanum.The handles are for changing the tension on the head, which changes the pitch of the drum. There is also a pedal which can be operated by foot, to go from one tuned pitch to another.
Valves are what they're not - there's no gas or liquid passing, only tension produced by a screwing motion.

Comment: The timpani used by the Vienna Philharmonic don't have pedals, they are tuned by hand with those handles.

Answer (score 4):

Timpani, and those handles change the tuning.

Answer (score 2):

It can be considered a dial with a solid rod mechanism that fine-tunes a kettle drum. Normally the player will set their pedal (lever) to the correct position before a piece and fine-tune while playing.